# Android Bluetooth 4.0 automatically shut down without exception.

Tags: android, bluetooth

Well, recently Google release the Android 4.3, and it support Bluetooth 4.0 device connection. Unlucy, I have a bluetooth 4.0 project before this appear. My testing phone is Samsung S4, so I can only use SamsungBLEConnect to implement the first version of my apps. And I meet a unexpected situation.

The bluetooth connector(hardware) and Wifi will automatically shut down by itself without any exception.

After this happen, we need to reactivate the bluetooth and wifi by using system setting. This is surely unacceptable for any client. And I don't believe we can program the apps to activate the bluetooth and wifi, as we surely cannot disable the client's bluetooth and wifi by any exception or logical error.

So, the situation is very weired, and the reason of this accident is unknown.

Answer (score 0):

> Restart your mobile first and then check it out

Comment: Why? Anyway, I have reboot the phone. The situation is keep going happen.